# Convert datatype datetime2 to datetime from textbox value storing a date (Jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, api, datetime

Im trying to take a datetime value from a text box using jquery and send it to an API

```
function getData() {   
var data = {      
    Date: ($("#Date").val()),        
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here I am receiving the data info and this is where the date will not set

```
public static AddData(DataDTO dateinfo)
    {
          var test = new Core.Data.Test();              
            test.Date = dateInfo.Date;

            context.SaveChanges();

            return test;
    }
```

I also have the dto object

```
public class DataDTO
{
 public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas how I parse this date? The out of the browser when I get the value from the textbox is e.g. 12/04/2017

Answer (score 0):

You should send a timestamp through your API then in your C# Retrieving method use this code below to convert the timestamp into C# DateTime object.

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    .AddMilliseconds(<retrieved Timestamp>)
    .ToLocalTime();
```

Reason behind this is, You add milliseconds to Epoch Date which in this case is 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.